# Remove Top bar/header/Main Nav links from one page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a landing page and I would like to remove the topbar and header/main Nav links from this page, and this page only.

Currently, I use this CSS code to remove it:

```
.top-headers-wrapper{display:none;}
```

However, it leaves a big blank white space in place of the header. Ideally this white space would be removed and the big background image would go all the way to the top of the page.

I illustrate the difference below, where the page with -test appended to the URL has the CSS to remove the header. The original URL does not have the code to remove the header.

How can I modify the code to remove this white space as well as the header/topbar?

https://www.californiabeardco.com/summer-giveaway/

https://www.californiabeardco.com/summer-giveaway-test/

Comment: Add example HTML and CSS demonstrating this issue to your question so when the issue is fixed on the remote site the question is still relevant.

Comment: Just letting you know that something is configured incorrectly with your WordPress; attempting to access your site automatically signed me in as you (with admin rights). You might want to look into that.

Comment: You have a margin top on your content-area wrapper causing the white space. Though probably better to solve this server side, that is, prepare the template specifically for what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I found a solution. It's a bit of a workaround but it worked nonetheless.

The solution I found was to create a page template (e.g., "Landing Page") with no headers, footers, or sidebar. This results in a blank page which, when using a page designer like Visual Composer, allows me to design on a blank canvas, perfect for creating a landing page.

I followed the steps from [this tutorial](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-page-without-header-menu-sidebar-and-footer/) but will post them here for anyone else with the problem:

1) create a new php file
2) paste in this code

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Clean Page
 * This template will only display the content you entered in the page editor
 */
?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();   
        the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

3) Upload the php file to the server hosting your Wordpress instance. The location should be your theme directory. Something such as ../wp-content/themes/YourThemeName

I added the php file to my child theme which worked fine, if you use a child theme, which is usually recommended protocol as I understand it.

4) Log onto the Wordpress admin console and when you create a new page, look for your newly added Template as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Your `content-area` class has a `top-margin` of `133px`. If you are removing the header altogther then you should be able to remove the top margin like this

```
#page_wrapper.transparent_header .content-area {
  top-margin: 0;
}
```

It looks like there are a couple of instances of this in the various `@media` queries in the CSS file. So you will have to find each instance.

Also like Obsidian mentions in the comments when I access your site I was logged in with admin privileges, you should change this as soon as possible. Hope that helps.

Comment: I added this code to the page's CSS but it did not fix it. I found an element in the CSS called ".vc_custom_1502310592874" and it has a top-margin value of -100px. When I modify it to 200px, the background image moves up a bit on the page but is not totally gone. I can't seem to isolate that background element to modify it's top-margin to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable admin bar by more elegant way, like go to Profile > uncheck the options *Show Toolbar when viewing site*.

Or if you want to completely disable admin bar for all logged in users, insert this code to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function remove_admin_login_header() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
```

Another way is use filter, completely disable for all logged in users too.

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution to the admin bar issue. Is it still available to you?